# Trouble parsing RSS feed for android

Tags: android, xml, rss, xml-parsing, document

OK, so I am trying to parse this [feed](http://www.gamestar.de/news/rss/news.rss) for an android application:

and I am doing it with this code:

```
    protected List<GamestarFeedItem> doInBackground(Context... params) {
    context = params[0];
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    List<GamestarFeedItem> items = new ArrayList<GamestarFeedItem>();
    test = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new URL("http://rss.feedsportal.com/c/370/f/5299/index.rss").openConnection().getInputStream());
        //Document document = builder.parse(new URL("http://www.gamestar.de/rss/gamestar.rss").openConnection().getInputStream());
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList docItems = root.getElementsByTagName("item");          
        Node nodeItem;

        for(int i = 0;i<docItems.getLength();i++){
            nodeItem = docItems.item(i);

            if(nodeItem.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                GamestarFeedItem feedItem = new GamestarFeedItem();
                NodeList element = nodeItem.getChildNodes();                    
                feedItem.setTitle(element.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                feedItem.setSummary(element.item(2).getNodeValue());
                feedItem.setLink(element.item(1).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());                   feedItem.setDate(element.item(3).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                //feedItem.setImage(element.getChild(""));
                test.add(element.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                String aaa = element.item(2).getNodeName(); 
                items.add(feedItem);
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return items;
}
```

Now, everything so far works right, except that this line :

```
feedItem.setSummary(element.item(2).getNodeValue());
```

just returns a `<` instead of the description, and with this line i know that i am trying to extract the right element:

```
String aaa = element.item(2).getNodeName();
```

Now, here is a example of such a description:

<a href="http://www.gamestar.de/news/vermischtes/2564931/gamepro_apps_fuer_ios_und_android.html"><img align="left" hspace="5" src="http://images.idgentertainment.de/images/idgwpgsgp/bdb/2275036/127x.jpg"/></a> Aktuelle News, Spiele-Tests, Previews und Releases für Xbox 360, PlayStation 3 und Vita sowie Nintendo-Systeme auch unterwegs immer dabei: Ab jetzt sind kostenfreie GamePro-Apps im Android Market und in iTunes verfügbar.<img width='1' height='1' src='http://rss.feedsportal.com/c/370/f/5299/s/1cbb8bf0/mf.gif' border='0'/><div class='mf-viral'><table border='0'><tr><td valign='middle'><a href="http://share.feedsportal.com/viral/sendEmail.cfm?lang=de&title=GamePro-Apps+f%C3%BCr+iOS+und+Android+-+Auf+dem+Smartphone+up-to-date+in+der+Welt+der+Konsolen-Spiele&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamestar.de%2Fnews%2Fvermischtes%2F2564931%2Fgamepro_apps_fuer_ios_und_android.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://rss.feedsportal.com/images/emailthis2.gif" border="0" /></a></td><td valign='middle'><a href="http://res.feedsportal.com/viral/bookmark_de.cfm?title=GamePro-Apps+f%C3%BCr+iOS+und+Android+-+Auf+dem+Smartphone+up-to-date+in+der+Welt+der+Konsolen-Spiele&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamestar.de%2Fnews%2Fvermischtes%2F2564931%2Fgamepro_apps_fuer_ios_und_android.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://rss.feedsportal.com/images/bookmark.gif" border="0" /></a></td></tr></table></div><br/><br/><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/126178574663/u/355/f/5299/c/370/s/1cbb8bf0/kg/300/a2.htm"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/126178574663/u/355/f/5299/c/370/s/1cbb8bf0/kg/300/a2.img" border="0"/></a><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/126178574663/u/355/f/5299/c/370/s/1cbb8bf0/kg/300/a2t.img" border="0"/>

So, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found the solution.

Because of the format of the "description", it actually consists of multiple child items, so u just extract those childs into a Nodelist and loop over them to extraxt their content and problem solved

```
    String bbb = new String();
    NodeList desc = element.item(2).getChildNodes();
    for(int j = 0;j<desc.getLength();j++){
        bbb += desc.item(j).getNodeValue();
    }
```